# Node.js: Google Calendar On Behalf of User

Tags: node.js, flutter, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, google-calendar-api

I am trying to access multiple users' Google Calendars in a search functionality with Flutter and Firebase Functions in Node.js.

I originally ask for user permission here in the app (Flutter):

```
 clientViaUserConsent(_credentialsID, _scopes, prompt)
        .then((AuthClient client) async {
```

The credentials for the user are then stored locally and in Firestore via a restricted Firebase Function for security reasons.
Calling Firebase Function (Node.js):

```
 FirebaseFunctions.instance
          .httpsCallable('addCalendar')
          .call(<String, dynamic>{
        'calendarAuthToken': client.credentials.accessToken.data,
        'calendarRefreshToken': client.credentials.refreshToken!,
        'calendarExpiration':
            client.credentials.accessToken.expiry.toString(),
        'idToken': client.credentials.idToken.toString()
      });
```

Firebase Function:

```
  return await admin.firestore().collection('[example text]').doc('[example text]').set({
    CalendarAccessToken: calendarAccessToken,
    CalendarRefreshToken: calendarRefreshToken,
    CalendarExpiration: calendarExpiration,
    // CalendarIDToken: calendarIDToken
}).then(() => {
```

I have a search functionality which needs access to all users' calendars. Obviously this should never be done locally due to the sensitivity of the data, so I am trying to do this in a Firebase Function as well.

```
exports.isAvailableNow = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
     const id = data.id;
     const cal= await admin.firestore().collection('[example text]').doc(id)
```

Should I be reconstructing user's credentials in the Firebase Function, or should I instead be using a service account? The reconstruction could get blocked because it is running on Firebase, not locally like the user permitted. If I need to use a service account, how does that change the original authorization in flutter?

EDIT: Changed the title

UPDATE: I managed to reconstruct the authentication for the user on the server-side, but my fear has become a reality. Google is saying I am not authorized for the user. How do I authorize a user on the client then access their data on the backend?

Comment: For starters are you aware that service accounts only work with Google calendar under workspace accounts with domain wide delegation configured?

Comment: @DaImTo yes, which is another reason why I am confused. I'm seeing suggestions on forms to use a service account for similar issues such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031946/google-calendar-to-manage-multiple-users-calendar) among others, which points me towards [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) on OAuth 2.0. Currently, I authorize with clientViaUserConsent(), which doesn't provide user secrets. What method should I use?

Comment: Depends are these gmail google calendar accounts you are accessing or just accounts on your workspace domain.    if it is all users on the domain then just use a service account just remember to delegate to each user one at a time.  The service account can only have access to a single user at a time so either create multiple objects or just loop though them.

Comment: These are gmail google calendar accounts I am accessing. They are not on a single domain. Users give the app access to the account for scheduling purposes. This could be anywhere from a few to a thousand users with their own gmail accounts.

Comment: if its normal gmail account then you need to use Oauth2 to authorize the user.  You will need to request access to their google calendar account first.  Tip: Take into account the time it will take you to verify an app using Google calendar api.     You cant use a service account.

Comment: @DaImTo I see, that is difficult, but we shall do it! Will the access code obtained on the client side work for Firebase Functions on the back-end?

Comment: that will depend on if you can use the same client id and client secrete to create it.   If you want to access a users calendar you need their permission.   Have you tried just inviting users to an internal calendar in your system then they should be notified and can decide if they want to add it to their calendar themselves.

Comment: @DaImTo I store the credentials from the clientViaUserConsent(), including the access code and the refresh token. Would these credentials be sufficient? I'm currently pursuing this route by creating a [webauth](https://isuruhettiarachchi.medium.com/google-calendar-api-with-oauth2-and-node-js-25f17521c1f3) from the user credentials as shown at step 04. I'm using my id and secret on initialization, then trying to call the calendar with that oauth.

Comment: @DaImTo I recreated the client on the backend, but since I have to use the web oauth 2.0 credentials, it is getting blocked. The user authorized on the Android credentials. Is there a scope or something I can add which I am currently missing?